# Javascript on ASP TextBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I dont undestand why, but my javascript doesnt work ...
I've some textbox like these:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SCAPULAIRE") %>' ID="txtScapulaire"/>
```

And i try to get the value of these textboxes. So i use javascript this way:

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtScapulaire.ClientID %>').value = 3;
```

But Visual studio tells me that "txtScapulaire is not declared". Maybe because of its protection.
Do you have any idea why it isnt working ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Otherthan the VS warning, does the code works ?

Comment: It's not a warning, that's the problem ^^

Comment: @user3272798 - The problem I think is,you have your textbox inside any databound control like _Gridview_ or _Repeater_ control. In that case it won't work like this.

Comment: Yes indeed, it is in a formview ... what can i do then ??

Answer (score 1):

I found it:

I've too do something liek that:

```
myformID.Findcontrol("txtscapulaire").ClientID
```

:D thanks